# Mixed (Analog and Digital) signal USB interface

Tags: usb, gpio, camera

I am working on the problem of having a USB interface be used for dual purpose: a normal digital session and an off-specification USB plug signaling.

To obtain a normal USB session no changes need to be made to the cable.

The off-specification signaling needs modification of the cable and is common among shutters of digital cameras. Example [Samsung NX1000 picture trigger](https://antibore.wordpress.com/2013/04/30/diy-remote-shutter-release-for-samsung-nx20-nx210-and-nx1000-cameras/).

[image]

What I would like to know is if I can safely trigger the circuit like in the image and on-demand change turn on the USB functionality with some form of GPIO.

The application I have in mind does not need both modes active at the same time, as I believe that would crash the USB session.

Comment: Can you offer a better source than a DIY blogger for the Samsung USB hack?  Is there an "official" description of this interface?

Comment: No. I have manually tried this hack and it works consistently and with many cameras. Basically the trigger is pulling down the data pins to ground. Nothing more. Do you have any specific question

Comment: Pulling around the data pins is not unusual, especially if the device is a USB slave. However, the resistor looks critical as well, so you should switch that in as well.

Answer (score 1):

The original intent of ID pin on mini/micro 5-pin connectors was to discriminate host from device on "dual-role ports", formerly "OTG ports". If ID is shorted (in cable side), the port must act as host. If ID is open, the port must act as USB device.

Intermediate resistance on ID pin is reserved for other uses of the port as audio outputs in so-called "Car Kit" application, or "accessory" (not sure what does it mean), or as UART debug port. Some IC supporting optional port features use 140k as the optional value, some 102k, it varies. These specifications are not openly published, so it is difficult to say. The value of 68k could be proprietary for the Samsung camera, and might not work for others. I am quite sure that if you use open collector (or open drain) output from your digital controller to emulate push switches, the design should work just fine, provided that your camera recognizes the ID=68k.

Addition: there appears to be a patent from Fairchild for this kind of control. Many cameras as Sony, Nikon are using something similar.